# how to link face detector api with the photo activity

Tags: android, face-detection

```
public class PhotoActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private ImageView imageView;
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private Bitmap bmp;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private Parameters parameters;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

    parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();

    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Call web service
            SendPhotoAsync photoToWeb = new SendPhotoAsync(data);
            photoToWeb.execute();
        }
    };
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    mCamera = Camera.open();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    try {

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```

how i could modify this code to detect face on camera preview,using face detector api in android.. any help please..
i also want to detect eyes then..hope someone can help me..i went through [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/04/face-detection-for-camera.html)which works on button click.in my case for taking photo no button click is there..
someone with some productive code will be appreciable..please help me its very critical

Comment: I don't know much about face detection but this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182849/face-detection-in-java

Comment: thank you sir i dont know how i could achieve this..still im thankful to you as you helped me to take 'a step' forward..thank you so much..i will go through the link..

Comment: There is a new face detector for Android which may serve your needs:  https://developers.google.com/vision/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the android API for face detector..call this activity from the photo activity..in photo activity save the captured image to sd card...read this file in the face detector api..thus we can make it..but samsung galaxy+google nexus doesnt perform face detection..AAkash does..